# Ruby on Rails - Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v4.9.1. Update it. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu

Working on a Rails app. Coworker pushed new commits to master with some new gems installed. Then I pulled the master branch to the local branch where I work on, the app breaks and displays the error on the title.

I use Ubuntu, the rest of the team use Macs.

Any ideas?

Already updated Node.js on my terminal to 10.x the current latest. But the error still display the `Node v4.9.1` message.

Ref: https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/137

Comment: did you try replacing ruby_racer with mini_racer.  According to ref link you have provided.https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/137#issuecomment-405850648

Comment: Had same issue, solved by adding mini_racer gem

Comment: Thanks guys. This has been solved by the mini_racer gem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For future searchers, we on our team can only duplicate this error on Ubuntu environment.(Tried it on iOS and Ubuntu 16.04 only)

Already tried installing the latest Node.js versions, to no avail.

There is a link in my question that talks about how this is happening and how to fix it.

So the solution was by installing the `mini_racer` gem to your rails app.

Comment: I wanted to comment that of all the solutions I found for this issue, installing mini_racer was the only one that worked.  Now, that said, I did upgrade bootstrap-sass earlier so perhaps both were needed but mini_racer was what apparently fixed things for me.

Comment: Perfect solution install `mini_raer` gem.

Answer (score 2):

you can replace therubyracer by mini_racer in Gemfile
just comment
`#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby`
and add
`gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby`

then simply run the command `bundle install` it worked in my case

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I updated my Node but nothing happened.
Then I looked at my Gemfile.lock and noticed some gems have some runtime dependancies to autoprefixer-rails (in my case it was bootstrap-sass). Then I upgraded the bootstrap-sass version to use a newer dependency of autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1).

Then I ran **bundle install** and deployed my app and the result was all good.

On a side note, if you are deploying to AWS, make sure to reboot your EC2 instance and watch /var/log/eb-activity.log.

Answer (score 0):

How topgraded the bootstrap-sass version to use a newer dependency of autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1).

Comment: can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 NodeJS installed i.e one with the NVM and the second one with the OS package manager (`apt`, `yum`, or `pacman`). You can check that as below,

```
node -v   #should give output for nvm version
nodejs -v #should give output for system package manager version
```

So to resolve this issue you can delete the NodeJS from the system package manager as below,

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

This should solve the issue but just to be on the safe side, you can remove the cache as below,

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```